# TideSDK and Symfony2

Tags: php, cross-platform, tidesdk

my plan is to using PHP in Tide.

I read the guides and I didn't figured out if its possible to use it with a big application written in Symfony2 (or other framework).

I just saw this tag  but I've no clue how to startup my Symfony2 app.

Is this possible?
Is there an additional resource to read?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer from the developers:

> TideKit includes Zend as part of our PHP but we don't encourage full
>   blown PHP app development since this can limit capabilities and
>   platforms for deployment. Therefore, we've not looked at frameworks
>   like Symphony, CodeIgniter, and others to ensure they can be used.
>
> Foremost, TideKit is a JS Platform that enables you to consistently
>   write your code once in a single language. With more than 100,000
>   packages of functionality available in JavaScript, there is not much
>   you cannot find these days (as opposed to write yourself). Together
>   with our native capabilities, TideKit is suitable for virtually
>   anything you can imagine for HTML5, hybrid, or native apps.
>
> We are currently working on our demos to provide a glimpse of
>   TideKit's capabilities. TideKit is very flexible to work with and
>   we'll be demonstrating app work flows that mean fast and enjoyable
>   development.

Source: https://blog.tidekit.com/post/from-a-desktop-perspective-tidekit-for-tidesdk-developers#comment-1568824440

As I have seen, it's a quite neat tool to have, but the PHP version is not the latest one (also webkit is pretty dated in it), so functions might not work exactly as they should. A major issue what I came accross when using Tide is that it does not treat directories pretty well. I had to set a lot of working directories inside the scripts (also with ifs so it would always point to the right directory) - it doesn't seem to like relative paths that much.

Anyway, I think it's a great tool, yes, it supports PHP, but if you were to use a framework with it, you probably would lose all your hair. If you plan to just write a light app in PHP on your own, that's perfectly fine then, but you still have to troubleshoot some due to the directory issue mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP inside of TideSDK. [Here is a good link to the documentation on how to use PHP with TideSDK](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/using_php) . I have not used Symfony2 before, but let me assure you that using javascript and html5 are two of the easiest languages are.

How I started using TideSDK:

When you download the TideSdk you are given a page "index.html". Use this as your start and then use the link of the documentation I gave you. Please follow of the necessary steps to enable PHP in your project. That is the way that I started my project. Hopefully I helped you get started. Please let me know if I didn't answer your question and you wanted a more specific answer. (Also make sure that you when you use the TideSDK Developer, you switch the PHP button to on.)